# How change permamently font in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I want to change a default font in MathJax. I want to have permamently an effect which appears when I put command like `$$\sf \frac{1}{2}ah$$`. Which file should I change to create this effect without using everywhere `\sf`?

It will be also nice to delete a bold which appear in font.

What is the reason why I need to change it? Standard italic TeX font didn't look so good on my page. Font from `\sf` looks much better.